# QMediaRecorder::supportedAudioCodecs() to recognize audio/opus?

Tags: qt, codec

I'm trying to make [QMediaRecorder::supportedAudioCodecs()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qmediarecorder.html#supportedAudioCodecs) to include [Opus Codec](http://www.opus-codec.org/).

I'm using Linux x86; QtVersion 4.7.3 with QtMobility.

I have installed all libOpus, Opustool and Opusfile.

But unlike other codec like vorbis and speechx,QMediaRecorder won't list Opus after install it.

Is this because QtMultimediaKit not support Opus? Or is there anyway to work around with this? My current task is to try recording to Opus Codec on Qt.